# USB stick not working

Tags: windows-7, usb

If I plug my memory stick in my Windows 7 computer, it does not function.

Normally, if the stick is recognized, there is a blue light on the stick, but not now. I'm sure that my stick works on other computers.

Comment: Just to clarify, your thumb drive works on various computers except your friend's laptop, and no other known-good thumb drives work on that laptop either, on any USB ports?

Comment: Here is similar thread [Windows 7 Professional doesn't mount my usb flash drive](http://superuser.com/questions/369888/windows-7-professional-doesnt-mount-my-usb-flash-drive-anymore) check whether this helps.

Comment: *"If I plug my memory stick..."* -- *Memory Stick* is/was a Sony product, and is not the same as a USB flash drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If it is recognize by Windows** (you can check Device Manager, type **devmgmt.msc** in Run dialogbox and hit enter) Then you only need to give it a drive letter to be able to see it at your Windows Explorer.

How to give a drive letter to a partition:

**First** you need to open **Disk Management**. There are two ways (At least!):

1. Open **Run** dialog. (Hit Windows Key + R or go to Start Menu and hit **Run...**)
2. Type **diskmgmt.msc** and hit Enter key to open **Disk Management** window.

**OR**

1. Click on **Start menu** then right click on **Computer** and select **manage**

.

**When** you open Disk Management window, do as fallow:

1. From Inside of Disk Management window and from its Top or Bottom Panel find your USB Stick partition.
2. Right click on it and from popup menu select "**Change Drive Letter and Path...**".
3. At new small window with title of "Change Drive Letter and Path" click on **Add** button.
4. From "**Assign the following drive letter:**" radio button, select any letter from **drop down list** and hit **OK** button.
5. **OK** the rest dialog boxes.

Now you should be able to see your USB Stick in (My) Computer window!